# Xamarin IOS storyboard scrollview doesn't scoll

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, xamarin-studio

I'm trying to create a signup form in a storyboard in the Xamarin Studio editor, but I can't get i to scroll.

I have set AutoLayout to false.

My Document outline can be seen at the picture:

[image]

And in my CreateUserViewController I have the following:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
   ScrollSignup.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize (1000, 1000);
   base.ViewDidLoad ();
}
```

The view is set to 700 in height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself. Just needed to a a view in the scroll view and let that view contain the elements